Model turned dark grey in Solid Mode, with odd white artefact
Blender 4.1.1. I am working in Solid Mode. Studio/Material lighting.
Working on this chest model, I noticed an odd dark grey artefact on one of the front faces. It was a bit like a shadow was being cast because the artefact did not cover an entire face, even though there are no lights in the scene. As a first step, I tried recalculating normals, and merging any duplicate vertices/edges. The model suddenly turned all dark grey, and the artefact was now white.
Looking at that single face in Flat-Light mode, there seems to be a sort of "fold" on it i.e. there is what appears to be an edge, either side of which is a different colour, but there IS NO EDGE!
When I switch to Object Mode, front view, the model is dark grey, white grey, black, and even a sort of "white noise" colour in patches all over. First thought is z-fighting, but there are no duplicate faces.
I tried exporting the model and reimporting into a new Blender file, but got the same thing.
Thanks in advance for any help you can give.
Blender file: 


Sorry, I don't know why the images haven't loaded

Please share your Blend file so that we can see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

To be honest I've never seen anything like it before. Maybe someone else here has an idea now that you've shared the file? Even duplicating that face and seperating it as a new object still displays the same odd shading on the new face! It's also fine if you load it into Blender 3.6 with no trace of shading problems!

Sorted it! Clear Custom Split Normals button on the Object Data (green triangle) > Geometry panel. No idea what could have caused it though. Was it modelled with a different program and imported into Blender originally?

Thank you so much! That worked. Yes, it was a model from a Synty pack

Now added as an answer.

The model was created in external software originally and has Custom Split Normals on it although I've never seen such a dramatic effect before.
These can be cleared under Data Properties > Geometry Data by clicking the Clear Custom Split Normals Data button.

The image below has the normals cleared on the bottom box but not the lid:

